# linux - "read -p" numbers [0-9] and "_" as imput

Tags: bash

This time Bash question. 
I am doing a script that will require user input `"read -p"`.
 
The problem is that file name is in that format: `vNN_NN_nn_nn_nn.zip`. For example `v3_11_1_2.zip` or `v_1_1_1_1_22.zip`
I can add into script `"v`" to be up front - no problem. 
The problem is how to read only `[0-9]` and `[_]` as a input parameter.
 
I tried all combinations and no success.

```
read -p "Please enter file name like 1_2_03_04: " filename
                if [ ! $filename =~ ^[0-9]+$ ] || [! $zip =~ ^[_]+$ ]; then
                        echo "Filename is not valid"
                else
                        echo "filename is $filename"
                fi
```

No success so far. How that can be done?
Thank you.

Comment: `^[0-9]+$` only allows digits, and `^[_]+` only allows underscores. you're doing two completely independent checks, neither of which allows all the characters you want to allow. so the 0-9 regex will fail because you have a `_`, and the `_` regex will fail because you have digits, and since they're totally independent of each other, can't cooperate to say "hey, this is actually ok". Why can't you just have a SINGLE regex `^v?[0-9_]+$`?

Comment: Done. Works. As mentioned earlier - i thought I have done that. Was mistaken :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of changes I would make. First, be sure to use `[[...]]` rather than `[...]`, as the former is BASH, and the later is just sh. The regex syntax is not just sh.

Next, you'll want to include both checks in the same regex. The `[...]` groups in regex can contain all the characters that you want to include.

Try this solution:

```
read -p "Please enter file name like 1_2_03_04: " filename
                if [[ ! $filename =~ ^[0-9_]+$ ]] ; then
                        echo "Filename is not valid"
                else
                        echo "filename is $filename"
                fi
```

Comment: i swear i have done that. Problem solved. Thank you. I really swar i have done that - that was my 1st attempt.

Comment: Yeah, I've been there before, when your first attempt has something you miss, so you think you're going crazy and try everything else. Sometimes, it just takes another set of eyes, or however many million are on this site.

Answer (score 2):

To support your format of filenames, I suggest using this regex:

```
re='^v[0-9]*(_[0-9]+)+$'

read -p "Please enter file name like v1_2_03_04: " file

[[ $file =~ $re ]] && echo "$file is valid" || echo "$file is not valid"
```

This will not allow weird looking filenames such as `v____` or `v12____` or `v12_1_`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uS4sJ4/2)